# cannot find javax.persistence annotations when using spring r2dbc

Tags: java, spring, h2, reactive, spring-reactive

I am trying to use reactive repositories with `H2` using `Spring Boot`.

I have added dependencies

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc:0.1.0.M1'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-r2dbc:0.1.0.M1'
implementation 'io.r2dbc:r2dbc-pool:0.8.0.RELEASE'
```

My domains looked like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "json_comparison")
public class JsonComparisonResult {
    @Column(name = "comparison_id")
    @Id
    private String comparisonId;
    @Column(name = "left")
    private String leftSide;
    ....
```

When the dependency was to

```
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:$springBootVersion"
```

Everything worked fine. But since I have added `r2dbc` dependencies it wasn't able to find any dependencies for `javax.persistence` annotations. When I use `starter-jpa` with reactive repositories it fails on startup (regular `Reactive Repositories are not supported by JPA`).

How to solve the problem? Add `javax.persistence` dependency manually?

What is the problem?

Comment: But it says: "Reactive Repositories are not supported by JPA"!? JPA is not supported because it's not reactive

Comment: I know. The problem is how to fix it as JPA provides a lot annotations. So far I decided to use annotations from `data.relational.core.mapping` and `data.annotation.Id` from spring framework libraries. But stuff like `Enumerated` doesn't have alternatives

Comment: So you have to wait until JPA becomes reactive as well...

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I will just play around with what exists now. Not for production of course.

Answer (score 4):

As a solution, I decided to switch to `org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping` annotations like `@Table`, `@Column` and  `org.springframework.data.annotation @Id`.

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;
```

In addition, I had to create tables manually via SQL scripts.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. How do we resolve the issue for classes Entity, JoinColumn, ManyToOne etc? Which dependency should we use?